# I need help to create a Geometry nodes that simulates Embroidery

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am trying to do a Geometry nodes that simulates Embroidery for a job, but what I've already done won't work for me.
These are my steps for my current setup:

My setup selects two first splines inside a curve object (any others splines are completely ignored
[image: enter image description here)]

Then it instantiates some line primitives along one of the splines
[image]

At last I realized the instances and select the top points of the created lines and set their position along the points of the remaining original spline
[image]

My problem is that I want to have the possibility to add an random transform for each of the created lines, but with my current setup I had to realize the instances in order to use the set position node.
Does anyone know another way that I could do that?
And of course, later using handles I would make the lines have a curvature to mimic embroidery

This is a print of my current setup:
[image]

Comment: Can you add a reference image of what this should look like?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for. But it might be helpful.

[image: embroidery]

Simon Thommes of the Blender Studio was showcasing a "stitch generator" with Geometry Nodes recently. The following node setup was replicated from the nodes shown in the video "[We can do that with Geometry Nodes...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1nvzwhbL-k0&t=1306s)". (Update: [download link](https://download.blender.org/demo/geometry-nodes/geometry_nodes_sample_uv_surface.blend) to the shown demo file.)

The modifier uses an input curve, then

- resamples it to create even distributed control points
- the *Filet Curves* node adds a few more points to smooth curve corners
- then it creates a "thread" from a curve
- and finally "stitches" the "threads" along the curve with some randomness for the thread length and rotation

[image: stitching geometry nodes]

When you edit the curve you can change the radius in the side panel to make the stitches larger or smaller (see screenshot 1).

The setting *Step Size* is how many threads you want to have on the curve. Smaller values result in more threads.

*Length Fac* is a factor for the length of the threads (=width of the embroidery) and *Height* is a factor for the height of the thread curves.

Last but not least, there are two more little modifiers to convert the curve into a mesh and to set the material.

[image: extrude curve and set material]

**Update:** Meanwhile you can download the file shown in the video at [blender.org - Demo Files](https://www.blender.org/download/demo-files/). It's the [Sample UV Surface](https://download.blender.org/demo/geometry-nodes/geometry_nodes_sample_uv_surface.blend)
Demo by Simon Thommes.

Comment: You're a saint man. Great answer.